# How does one to get the #id of an element from a clicked link using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jQuery/javascript here and looking for a little help. I am writing a site with a simple navigation menu. It works like this. A user clicks a link in the menu, the link is set to an 'active' colour and the appropriate section is set from hidden to visible ( all of the sections are set to hidden when the document loads ). When the user clicks another link that link is set to the active color, the others are set to the default colour, any visible sections are set to hidden and the relevant section is set to visible. This works just fine, but I used individual element and its very ugly with a lot of repetition. I am in the process of rewriting the code to use .classes and be a little bit more flexible with less repeated code.

The Question I have is this: How do I tell it what section to show?

User clicks on a.linkfornavigation, colour is set, section.blah are set to hidden, section#thisiswhatyouwant is set to visible. But how do I tell a.linkfornavigation where it should point? each section has a unique #id ( I guess so could the link they click ) but how do I get the #id of the relevant linked section from the clicked link?

Any help at all would be very much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>     
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/linkthinger-hybrid.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/linkthinger-hybrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <section id="links">
      <a class="thinger" href="#">Thing One</a>
      <a class="thinger" href="#">Thing Two</a>
      <a class="thinger" href="#">Thing Three</a>
      <a class="thinger" href="#">Thing Four</a>
      <a class="thinger" href="#">Thing Five</a>
    </section>

    <section id="things">
      <section id="thingone"   class="thing">I am thing one.</section>
      <section id="thingtwo"   class="thing">I am thing two.</section>
      <section id="thingthree" class="thing">I am thing three.</section>
      <section id="thingfour"  class="thing">I am thing four.</section>
      <section id="thingfive"  class="thing">I am thing five.</section>
    </section>

  </body>
```

javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

//  Hides .thing class as soon as the DOM is ready.
//  $('section.thing').hide(0);

//  Highlight selected link & set all others to default.  
  $('#links a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });

//  Shows one section and hides all others on clicking the noted link.
  $('a.thinger').click(function() {
    $('section.thing').hide(0);
    $('#thingone').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });

})
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: darkgreen;
    }

.selected {
    color: red;
    }

section.thing {
    background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Btw: A good site for examples like this is jsfiddle.net

Comment: You can access the links by array index, the way you access the sections by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the links proper `href` values. In this case it would be the IDs of the elements:

```
<a class="thinger" href="#thingone">Thing One</a>
<a class="thinger" href="#thingtwo">Thing Two</a>
....
```

The advantage is that clicking on the links will make the browser jump to the corresponding element, even if JavaScript is disabled.

Then you access this attribute and use it as ID selector for jQuery:

```
$('a.thinger').click(function() {
    $('section.thing').hide(0);
    $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: YES! After walking away for a few min thats exactly what I was thinking! Backwards compatibility saves me from my next question too. Thanks for the code and +1 for making me feel like I might be getting the hang of this!

Comment: So here is a follow up... Why does this not work if I wrap the <a> links in an unordered list <ul><li><a class="thinger" href="#">Thing One</a></li><li><a class="thinger" href="#">Thing Two</a></li></ul> My guess is that when marked up like that they are no longer siblings?

Comment: @Don: You mean the previous selected link is not deselected? Yes, that is because they are not siblings. You could do: `$(this).closest('ul').find('.selected').removeClass('selected')`.

Comment: Yes that has the conclusion I came to my self. I was able to get it to work useing $(this).parent('li').siblings().find("a").removeClass('selected'); what is the advantage of using .closest('ul') over .parent('li')? Would closest provide a more specific selection? (Although I am switching to .find(.'selected') over .find('a') as that seems more targeted then .find('a'))

Comment: Also, another conundrum if your so inclined to take a look... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324245/how-to-reset-background-colour-after-it-is-changed-by-jquery

Comment: @Don: `closest('ul')` will always find the closest `ul` element in the hierarchy,  no matter what the actual structure is. I.e. if you put the link, say, inside a `<span>`, then you have to adjust your code again. If you use `closest`, you don't have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the id of a clicked element do: `this.id`

To tell it what section to open you can add some `data-` attribute to determine it:

```
<section id="links">
  <a class="thinger" href="#" data-open="thingone">Thing One</a>
  <a class="thinger" href="#" data-open="thingtwo">Thing Two</a>
  <a class="thinger" href="#" data-open="thingthree">Thing Three</a>
  <a class="thinger" href="#" data-open="thingfour">Thing Four</a>
  <a class="thinger" href="#" data-open="thingfive">Thing Five</a>
</section>
```

JS:

```
  $('#links a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.thing').hide();
    $("#"+$(this).data('open')).show();
  });
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/sxrap/

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$('#thingone').fadeIn('slow');
```

To this:

```
$('#things .thing').eq($(this).index('a.thinger')).fadeIn('slow');
```

It works because `$(this).index('a.thinger')` returns an integer index of the anchor clicked, and `.eq(i)` returns a jQuery object containing the `i`th element from the JQuery object it's called on.

jQuery Docs:

- [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score -1):

`alert($(this).attr('id');` if you are staying true to jQuery

Comment: The links in OP's example don't have ids.